# why does Scapy opens a powershell.exe instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, scapy, sniffing

I'm using `scapy` and when I use the module `sniff`, a Powershell instance appears.

Why does that happen and how do I disable/replace with a python alternative?

Also, if all I want is to `sniff` packets, must I import the entire `sniff` module? It imports tons of other modules I might not need -  I need it to be as light as possible.

Appreciate any kind of help!!

[image: You can see what I meant with this screenshot]

Comment: Might want to check the source code and see where the PowerShellManager() constructor lives. From seeing this:
`https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1035`

Comment: yeah I've got to where the powershell command is actually being executed. but idk if it's gonna damage the performance of scapy. this issue references to a non existed solution btw

Answer (score 2):

Powershell is used in Scapy under Windows to get the host's network configuration (devices, routes, etc.).

It is, however, a bug that it opens windows. This bug [is beeing fixed](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1394) in the current development version.

Next release (2.4.1) will include the fix.